# MWS Stranded Inventory Report

Tags: amazon-mws

Am looking for an API to access the stranded inventory report in MWS. Apparently, can only access it via sellercentral. Does'nt seem to have any API unlike the rest of the inventory reports. If anyone is aware, do let me the name of API and parameter list if any, pls.

Regards
Kallol

Comment: Yeah, it's not available on MWS.  Perhaps you can contact the MWS team and request it or find out if the information about stranded inventory is available on another report that is on MWS.  I don't see any, but it's worth a shot.  https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html

Answer (score 1):

Stranded inventory by definition is inventory held at an Amazon Fulfillment Center which is not available for sale on Amazon.

You should be able to cross reference the FBA Inventory Report with a Listings report to obtain the information contained in the stranded inventory report.  The reports of interest are listed below:

_GET_FBA_MYI_UNSUPPRESSED_INVENTORY_DATA_
_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_

Answer (score 1):

This is now available in MWS using the report `enum` `_GET_STRANDED_INVENTORY_UI_DATA_`. Hope this will be help others download the report using the API way.